# Integrating of Google Login API in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, e-commerce

Currently I am working on making an e-commerce site using nodejs and mongodb. I want to integrate Google's API on the signup and login pages. Do the experts have any idea about this?

Comment: here you go. http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/

Comment: Hey Jash, You can take reference of this example-  https://github.com/Khushbu-2112/OAuth-google-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following link, though It's already been mentioned in the comments below your question.

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users

It's the official google cloud platform documentation on how to get started authenticating users on node js. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use the GoogleStrategy of passport.js library.
example:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const { OAuthStrategy: { GoogleStrategy } } = require('passport-google-oauth');

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    consumerKey: GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback"
  },
  (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
      User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
      });
  }
));
```

read docs for more details http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you so mucb.